# loading constant in xmm register

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, sse

I try to load a constant 4  in the xmm0 register, but my program always returns 0. Why is that so?

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.global pi

.section .rodata
const4: .word 4

.text
pi:
    movss xmm0, [rip + const4]
    ret
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `.float 4.0`?   Integer 4 is a bit-pattern that represents a very-small subnormal float.  (But not `0`, so whatever you're doing to check the return value is either rounding the value like `printf %f` (after converting to double), or is totally broken, we don't know which because you don't say.  Also this is just a function, not a whole program, but you say your *program* returns 0?  As in exit status?  Or are you still talking about this function)

Comment: thanks it works now. Yeah i mean the function sry. And i thought that you can only specify the size with byte, word, dword and qword

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of size overrides like `movss xmm0, dword ptr [rip + const4]`.  GAS has several data directives like `.int`, `.4byte`, and so on.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/.  Also note that `.word` is only 2 bytes on x86, not large enough to hold a `float` anyway.

Comment: yea exactly now it becomes clearer thanks